# AngularJS: Best way to handle global variables ($rootScope or global service?)

Tags: angularjs

I'm torn between using $rootScope and a global service.

$rootScope feels dirty and comes with all the problem of global variables, so I wanted to use a global service but the Angular FAQ says:

> Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly,
>   like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language.
>   In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to
>   put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a
>   service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily
>   tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to
>   store and return bits of data.

...and that's what I want to use the service for.

For example, I have a navbar that when toggled on mobile screens should add a class to the body and html elements. I handle this with a directive and a controller.

NavbarController:

```
function NavbarController($rootScope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.toggleNav = toggleNav;
    $rootScope.navCollapsed = false;

    function toggleNav() {
        $rootScope.navCollapsed = !$rootScope.navCollapsed;
    }
}
```

As you can see there, I'm using rootScope for the navCollapsed value and in my directive I do this:

```
function navOpen($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return $rootScope.navCollapsed;
            }, function () {
                if ($rootScope.navCollapsed)
                    element.addClass('nav-open');
                else
                    element.removeClass('nav-open');
            });
        }
    };
}
```

It works fine, but using $rootScope feels dirty. I would much rather do something like this:

NavbarController:

```
function NavbarController(globalService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.toggleNav = toggleNav;
    globalService.navCollapsed = false;

    function toggleNav() {
        globalService.navCollapsed = !globalService.navCollapsed;
    }
}
```

And in the directive:

```
function navOpen(globalService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return globalService.navCollapsed;
            }, function () {
                if (globalService.navCollapsed)
                    element.addClass('nav-open');
                else
                    element.removeClass('nav-open');
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Which does the exact same thing except now the value is in a single location and can't be unintentionally altered elsewhere which is better, but according to AngularJS team that is bad practice because it's "bits of data".

What is the best way of going about this? I have other variables with similar functionality that need to be global (able to be accessed in any controller for manipulation), without having to use $rootScope.

Comment: Why would you store the state of the navbar in a global service or in rootScope? Why not store it in the scope of the controller of the navbar? Nobody else needs that state, right? So that's where it belongs. Your directive is also useless. All you need is ng-class in the template of the navbar to add/remove a CSS class.

Comment: The css class is being used for the body/html tags and the navbar is being included with ng-include in my states so it has a different scope. When the navbar-toggle is clicked, it should add nav-open class to the html/body tags. That's why I'm using a directive (I could still use ng-class with the rootscope variable but I prefer to use a directive to keep the html cleaner) -- regardless, I'd still have to use rootscope so I can access the value on the html/body tags, not the navbar. Unless theres another way..

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. Use standard directives when they do the job that you need to do. And if the controller is supposed to drive the state of the body element, then use it on the body element. Although I don't see why you would need to set a CSS class on the body to open a navbar. Your code doesn't do that, BTW: it sets the CSS class on the navbar directive element.

Comment: the 'nav-open' directive is on the html/body tags, not on the navbar. And I am not using the default navbar from bootstrap, I made one myself so the body/html slide over and navbar comes from the left (this is for mobile screens). With jquery it's easy but I can't use jquery because the navbar won't have loaded yet in the DOM so it doesn't work, which is another reason why I used a directive.

Comment: @ryeballar that's exactly what I'm doing now. Unless by classes you actually mean classes and not tags..

Comment: As I said. You could simply use <body ng-controller="MainCtrl"> and do that in the main controller. But if you absolutely want to use a service because you need to access/control the navbar from two separate pices of code, then define a Navbar service, and expose a toggle() and isOpened() method in that service. Don't use rootScope for that.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think about a global controller lol. doing <html ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl"> won't be a problem, right? Can the controller be used with the same line as the module or does it have to be like a child?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Works like a charm :D Thanks. I think I will make a service for the navbar though because I have places where certain parts of it need to be hidden or altered based on what state you're on and I'd rather not have a bunch of conditions in the view when I could juse inject and call methods on the service in each controller, keeping the view a bit cleaner. Do you think that is a good practice?

Comment: Yes. If the you want to encapsulate functionality for a specific matter, and this functionality is used in various components, then a service is what you need.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help!